# "Ubuntu on a stick" devices?

Tags: arm, raspberrypi

Is anyone aware of any good "PC on a stick" or "System on a stick" devices that are good to run Ubuntu 12.10 - or even better, have Ubuntu preinstalled? ARM or x86.

I'm looking for something like Raspberry Pi, except that Ubuntu is not supported on it since its ARM processor is too old for Ubuntu 12.10.

On a related note, how is software/application support for Ubuntu on ARM? Is it up to par with the x86 packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MK802 III (Wikipeda)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Mini_PC_MK802) [(Amazon)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A0I4YJK) is one such device. It has a newer processor and the manufacturer is the Chinese-based Rikomagic. The processor is based off the AllWinner-A8, and it supports the newest version of Ubuntu (12.10). The MK802 III is the newest version of the MK802, and goes for about $80 USD + S&H. You can find older versions for less money. It has built-in wifi and HDMI support.

The [Cotton Candy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton_Candy_%28single-board_computer%29) is another such device that also has built-in wifi and HDMI. It, however, was originally meant as a device for developers, and can go for around $200 USD. Its processor is based off the ARM Cortex-A9 Exynos processor created by Samsung.

Answer (score 1):

Snappy Ubuntu-Core is now in alpha on Raspberry Pi 2 model B.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Comment: [Getting started with Snappy Ubuntu Core on the Raspberry Pi 2](https://darrenjw2.wordpress.com/2015/02/07/getting-started-with-snappy-ubuntu-core-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/)

Comment: Snappy is in reality a new distribution.